# Recoger una Imagen junto a unos datos que subo a Firebase y mostrarlo en un RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-studio, base-de-datos, firebase, recyclerview

Tengo un programa que recoge los datos de un Aviso (Nombre, descripcion y Ubicacion) luego me faltaria que recogiera la foto que se subo al Firebase Storage. Como podria hacer para relacionar la imagen que subo a cuando muestro los datos del Aviso?? Dejo el codigo de los ficheros que uso, para ver que podria cambiar/añadir. Muchas gracias. Up

**Fichero Fotos para hacer y subir las imagen a Firebase**

```
public class Fotos extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Controles para la camara/galeria
    private static String APP_DIRECTORY = "MyPictureApp/";
    private static String MEDIA_DIRECTORY = APP_DIRECTORY + "PictureApp";

    private final int PHOTO_CODE = 200;
    private final int SELECT_PICTURE = 300;

    private String mPath;
    private Bitmap imageBitmap;

    private StorageReference mStorage;

    ImageView foto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.foto_layout);

        foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);

        mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

        //Botones para abrir las Actividades (Camara/Galeria/Siguiente)
        Button camara = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camara1);
        camara.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openCamera();
            }
        });

        //Metodo para abrir la Galeria
        Button galeria = (Button) findViewById(R.id.galeria);
        galeria.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                openGaleria();
            }
        });

        //Metodo para pasar la foto a la Actividad MenuAvisos
        Button siguiente = (Button) findViewById(R.id.siguiente);
        siguiente.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                openSiguiente();
            }
        });
    }

    //Metodo para abrir la Camara de Fotos
    private void openCamera()
    {
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), MEDIA_DIRECTORY);
        boolean isDirectoryCreated = file.exists();

        if(!isDirectoryCreated)
            isDirectoryCreated = file.mkdirs();

        if(isDirectoryCreated)
        {
            Long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
            String imageName = timestamp.toString() + ".jpg";

            mPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + MEDIA_DIRECTORY + File.separator + imageName;

            File newFile = new File(mPath);

            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(newFile));

            startActivityForResult(intent, PHOTO_CODE);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap drawableToBitmap (Drawable drawable)
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;

        if(drawable instanceof BitmapDrawable)
        {
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) drawable;
            if(bitmapDrawable.getBitmap() !=null)
            {
                return bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }

        if(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() <= 0 || drawable.getIntrinsicHeight() <= 0)
        {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(1,1, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }
        else {
            bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable.getIntrinsicHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        }

        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
        drawable.setBounds(0,0, canvas.getWidth(), canvas.getHeight());
        drawable.draw(canvas);

        return bitmap;
    }

    //Depende la seleccion de Camara/Galeria (Case) hace una cosa o otra para mostrar las imagenes
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, final Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){
            switch (requestCode){
                case PHOTO_CODE:
                    MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(this, new String[] { mPath }, null, new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "Scanned" + path + ":");
                            Log.i("ExternalStorage", "-> Uri = " + uri);
                        }
                    });
                    imageBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(mPath);
                    break;
                case SELECT_PICTURE:
                    //FireBase Storage
                    Uri path = data.getData();
                    StorageReference filePath = mStorage.child("Fotos Aviso").child(path.getLastPathSegment());
                    filePath.putFile(path).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Toast.makeText(Fotos.this, "Se ha subido la foto a FireBase!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    //Mostrar la imagen
                    foto.setImageURI(path);
                    imageBitmap = drawableToBitmap(foto.getDrawable());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }

    //Metodo para abrir la Galeria
    private void openGaleria()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
        intent.setType("image/*");

        startActivityForResult(intent.createChooser(intent, "Selecciona app de imagen"), SELECT_PICTURE);
    }

    //Metodo para enviar la foto a la Actividad MenuAvisos*
    private void openSiguiente()
    {
        Intent intent=new Intent();
        imageBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(imageBitmap, 200, 150, true);
        ByteArrayOutputStream bs = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        imageBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,50,bs);
        intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",bs.toByteArray());
        setResult(RESULT_OK,intent);

        finish();
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString("file_path", mPath);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);

        mPath = savedInstanceState.getString("file_path");
    }
}
```

**Fichero donde recojo todos los Datos del Aviso y lo sube a la BBDD de FireBase**

```
public class MenuAvisos extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener  {

    public static final int FOTO_KEY = 66;
    public static final int MAPS_KEY = 11;

    TextView aviso1;
    EditText textDes;
    Button ubicacion;
    TextView textubi;
    ImageButton addfoto;
    ImageView foto;
    Button guardar;

    public FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

    private DatabaseReference databaseReference;

    String nombre;
    String ubi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.menuaviso_layout);

        aviso1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.aviso);
        textDes = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.descripcion);
        ubicacion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ubicacion);
        textubi = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textUbi);
        addfoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addfoto);
        foto = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.foto);
        guardar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.guardar);

        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();



        //Intent para recojer el nombre de la ListView
        Intent intent1 = getIntent();
        if(nombre!=null)
        {
            aviso1.setText(String.valueOf(nombre));
        }
        else
        {
            nombre = intent1.getStringExtra(ViewAviso.NOMBRE_KEY);
            aviso1.setText(String.valueOf(nombre));
        }

        //Metodo para abrir el mapa de la Ubicacion
        View.OnClickListener listener1 = new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                openMaps();
            }
        };
        ubicacion = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ubicacion);
        ubicacion.setOnClickListener(listener1);

        //Metodo para abrir la Class de Fotos *
        addfoto = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.addfoto);
        addfoto.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                openFotos();
            }
        });

        guardar.setOnClickListener(this);


    }

    //onActivity para mostrar la Imagen de la Actividad Fotos Y Para sacar el contenido del String ubi
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if(requestCode==FOTO_KEY)
        {
            byte[] byteArray = data.getExtras().getByteArray("MESSAGE");
            if(byteArray != null)
            {
                Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
                foto.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            }
        }
        //Para mostrar la dni (String ubi de MapsActivity)
        if(requestCode==MAPS_KEY && resultCode==RESULT_OK)
        {

            ubi = data.getStringExtra(MapsActivity.UBICACION_KEY);
            textubi.setText(ubi);
        }

    }

    //Metodo para abrir la Class de Fotos (Camara/Galeria)
    private void openFotos()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Fotos.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent, FOTO_KEY);
    }

    //Metodo para abrir la Class de Maps
    private void openMaps()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MapsActivity.class);

        startActivityForResult(intent, MAPS_KEY);
    }

    //Metodo para abrir la Class de Revisar (Donde enviamos toda la informacion del ListaAvisos)
    private void openEnviar()
    {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Verificar.class);

        String aux1 = aviso1.getText().toString();
        String aux2 = textDes.getText().toString();
        String aux3 = textubi.getText().toString();

        intent.putExtra("aviso", aux1);
        intent.putExtra("apellidos", aux2);
        intent.putExtra("dni", aux3);

        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private void saveInformation()
    {
        //getting current user
        FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        Aviso avisos = new Aviso();
        //Getting values from database
        avisos.setAviso(aviso1.getText().toString());
        avisos.setDescripcion(textDes.getText().toString());
        avisos.setUbicacion(textubi.getText().toString());

        //Creamos un objeto para guardar la informacion
        //Aviso avisoInformation = new Aviso(aviso,apellidos,dni,usuario);
        FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();

        final DatabaseReference myRef = database.getReference("Aviso").child(user.getUid()); //Aviso + Uid del Usuario
        Aviso aviso2 = new Aviso(avisos.getAviso(),avisos.getDescripcion(),avisos.getUbicacion());
        myRef.push().setValue(aviso2); //Push crea un Uid para cada Aviso

        //displaying a success toast
        Toast.makeText(this, "Guardando informacion del aviso, espera...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        //if logout is pressed
        if (view == guardar)
        {
            saveInformation();
            openEnviar();
        }
    }
}
```

**Fichero que uso para mostrar todos los Aviso y sus datos**

```
public class VerAvisos extends MenuAvisos
{

    FirebaseDatabase database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

    List<Aviso> avisos;
    RecyclerView rv;
    AdaptadorAvisos adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.recycler_avisos);

        avisos = new ArrayList<>();

        rv=(RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvAvisos);
        rv.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        adapter = new AdaptadorAvisos(this,avisos);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);

        database.getReference("Aviso").child(user.getUid()).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                avisos.clear();
                for(DataSnapshot snapshot :
                        dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                    Aviso aviso2 = snapshot.getValue(Aviso.class);
                    avisos.add(aviso2);

                }
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
```

**Codigo de Aviso**

```
public class Aviso {

    String aviso;
    String descripcion;
    String ubicacion;


    public Aviso(){
    }


    public Aviso(String aviso, String descripcion, String ubicacion){
        this.aviso = aviso;
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }

    public String getAviso() {
        return aviso;
    }

    public void setAviso(String aviso) {
        this.aviso = aviso;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public String getUbicacion() {
        return ubicacion;
    }

    public void setUbicacion(String ubicacion) {
        this.ubicacion = ubicacion;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {

        return  "Nombre Aviso: " +aviso+ " \n" +
                "Descripcion: " +descripcion + " \n" +
                "Ubicacion: " +ubicacion;

    }
}
```

Comment: Lo resolviste? necesito hacer lo mismo.

Answer (score -1):

Eso va a depender mucho de para que pienses usar esas imágenes. Al subir un archivo a storage éste queda vinculado a un path dentro del mismo (ej: /fotos/47259827.jpg ), este es el path que debes usar si quieres descargar el archivo mediante el API de storage y serás el único que pueda acceder a la misma.

Si lo que vas a hacer es mostrar esas imágenes en una lista mi recomendación es que cuando subas el archivo solicites el link directo `storageRef.child("fotos/12345.jpg").getDownloadUrl()` y que guardes ese link en tu objeto Aviso. La ventaja de esto es que esta url (autogenerada, no adivinable) es **publica** y por lo tanto se puede usar en frameworks como [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/) o [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) para hacer el manejo de imágenes (recomendado), la desventaja es obviamente que quien consiga esa url va a poder acceder a tu imagen.

Si bien es posible integrar estos frameworks con el API de storage esto crea un caos de hilos y paralelización que creeme te va a generar más dolores de cabeza de los que resuelve. A menos que tu contenido sea sensible, te sugiero que lo hagas con el link directo.